# Convert Html to Pdf using pachkin my some word are english & Arbic

Tags: c#

When I Convert HTML To PDF using `Pachkin` its working fine, but in HTML file some word are English And Some are Arbic but in PDF file Arabic word is not showing Properly
it show like

> %u0645%u0644%u0627%u062D%u0638%u0629 %u0647%u0627%u0645%u0629 :
>   %u0647%u0630%u0629 %u0627%u0644%u0627%u062F%u0627%u0629 %u0627%u0648
>   %u0627%u0644%u0645%u0639%u062F%u0629 %u0627%u0648
>   %u0627%u064A%u0643%u0627%u0646 %u0634%u064A%u0621 %u062A%u0645
>   %u062A%u0633%u0644%u064A%u0645%u0647 %u0647%u0648 %u0645%u0644%u0643
>   %u0644%u0645%u0635%u0646%u0639 %u0645%u0627%u062C%u062F
>   %u0627%u0644%u0631%u0642%u064A%u0639%u064A%u0644%u0645%u0648%u0627%u062F
>   %u0627%u0644%u0628%u0646%u0627%u0621
>   %u0648%u0627%u0644%u062A%u0639%u062F%u064A%u0646
>   %u0648%u0627%u062A%u0644%u0627%u0641%u0647
>   %u0628%u0623%u064A%u062D%u0627%u0644 %u0645%u0646
>   %u0627%u0644%u0627%u062D%u0648%u0627%u0644 %u064A%u0639%u0631%u0636
>   %u0645%u0646 %u0642%u0627%u0645 %u0628%u0627%u0644%u062A%u0644%u0641
>   %u0628%u0637%u0631%u064A%u0642%u0629
>   %u0645%u0628%u0627%u0634%u0631%u0629 %u0627%u0648 %u063A%u064A%u0631
>   %u0645%u0628%u0627%u0634%u0631%u0629
>   %u0644%u0644%u0645%u0633%u0627%u0626%u0644%u0647
>   %u0648%u0627%u0644%u0642%u0627%u0646%u0648%u0646
>   %u0648%u0627%u0644%u0627%u062F%u0627%u0629
>   %u0627%u064A%u0643%u0627%u0646%u062A
>   %u062A%u062D%u062A%u0645%u0633%u0624%u0648%u0644%u064A%u0629
>   %u0627%u0644%u0645%u0633%u062A%u0644%u0645
>   %u0643%u0627%u0645%u0644%u0629

Note : This Propery
is belongs to `AlRikai` for construction materials & mining Company. Please handle with care and if any damage or
misses in such cases Allocation person is responsible for the sam

Please help me out..

Comment: Those are URL encoded characters, not English or Arabic text. Where is the *original* data and how did it end up like this? Post your code

Comment: BTW you don't need to convert anything to write Unicode characters in an HTML or any other text file. Just make sure the file is saved as UTF8 (the default eg for File.WriteAllText) and the page header specifies UTF8. All web sites by now do this. Somehow, somewhere the code performed an unnecessary encoding.

Comment: Show some code how you convert html to pdf with Pachkin. It seems unicode http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/0645/index.htm

Comment: yes sir, i am using javascript (escape($("#DivPrint").html());) Encode html code

Comment: for Decode  attechment = Uri.UnescapeDataString(attechment); But Arbic  word  is not Decode.....

Answer (score 0):

i am using

HttpUtility.UrlDecode(attechment, System.Text.Encoding.Default);

for Unescape string  its working fine